# Why does Resharper want to cast my object to its base class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Resharper keeps trying to insert a cast to my base class and I cannot determine why.  It's when I'm writing a property setter for my view-model that derives from my base view-model class (named `Observable`), which is just like a million other implementations of `INotifyPropertyChanged` that you've seen.

(Note: I am sure this is Resharper because the behavior stops when I Suspend it.)

This is the property implementation I am *trying* to write.  I have done this in a hundred different properties already

```
public Point ScanPos 
{
    get => _scanPos; 
    set => SetProperty(ref _scanPos, value); 
}

private Point _scanPos;
```

But as I'm typing the setter, I get to here, I've just finished typing `SetProperty` and I'm about to type the `(`

[image]

Then I hit the `(`character and Resharper does *this*

[image]

For sake of completeness, here is the base class `Observable.SetProperty` implementaion

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(
    ref T                      currentValue,
    T                          newValue,
    [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
{
    if (Equals(currentValue, newValue))
        return false;

    currentValue = newValue;
    // ReSharper disable once ExplicitCallerInfoArgument
    RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

Now I can disable this if I must by adding the `(` character to the list of characters that do NOT result in auto-complete.  But I like using that character.  What I cannot understand is why the autocomplete itself inserts a cast to the base class.

The `SetProperty` function is not virtual; I do not override it anywhere.  Nor do I re-implement with `new`.

Can someone point me to the Resharper option that would make its auto-complete do this so I can turn it off?